# Combining two batch files / "do"ing more than one command per "do"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

Essentially what I want is to get the the user that's currently using a computer. I got the below code from this community which works well...,

```
::Batch 1    

@echo off

for /f %%a in (output1.txt) do WMIC /NODE:%%a computersystem GET name, username 

do echo %%r >> output2.txt
```

..., except that my computer names have hyphens in them and cannot be used.

To circumvent that, I run the below code (also got this here, thanks again!) to retrieve the IPs first:

```
::Batch 2

@echo off

for /f %%a in (hosts.txt) do call :process %%a

goto :eof


:process

set hostname=%1

for /f "tokens=4 delims=: " %%r in ('ping -n 1 %hostname%^|find /i "Statistics"') do echo %%r >> output2.txt
```

I then feed this information to the first batch file above to get the hostnames.

So essentially I place my hostnames on a txt file named Hosts.txt, run batch 2, then run batch 1.

I've tried many days to combine the both, but cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: You can use the syntax `for ..... do (echo 1 echo 2) to do more things at once. If you choose that one, please search the keywords `DelayedExpansion` :)

Comment: Either do `for ... do command_1 & command_2 & ...`, or `for ... do (` + _line-break_ + `command_1` + _line-break_ + `command_2` + _line-break_ + `...` + _line-break_ + `)`; see also this: [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html).

Answer (score 1):

As @aschipfl suggested. Use `FOR /?` to see information about using the `FOR` command.

```
for /f %%a in (output1.txt) do (
    WMIC /NODE:%%a computersystem GET name, username 
    ECHO right here
)
```